# UIImageView GestureRecognizer Not Working

Tags: iphone

I have the following code which adds the UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_circle"]];
    [circleView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [circleView setFrame:CGRectMake(20 + 60 * ([self.tasks count] - 1), self.bounds.size.height - 300, 44, 44)];

    // register gestures
    [self registerGestureRecognizer:circleView];

    [self addSubview:circleView];


-(void) registerGestureRecognizer:(UIImageView *) circleView
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self; 
    [circleView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"tapped!");
}
```

But when I touch the image the tapped method is never called! Am I missing something.

The view which contains the UIImageView is added to the UIScrollView.

UPDATE: Here is the code that adds a TaskView to the UIScrollView

```
-(TaskView *) createTaskView
{
    TaskView *taskView = [[TaskView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    taskView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    taskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [taskView.textView setDelegate:self];

    return taskView;
}

-(void) initializeScrollViewWithTasks
{
    for(int day = 1; day <= 7; day++)
    {
        TaskView *taskView = [self createTaskView];
        taskView.tag = day;
       // [_taskViews addObject:taskView];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:taskView];
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Totally my fault! I was doing something crazy when adding items to the UIScrollView. Fixed it!

Comment: Works fine for me. You may need to enable user interaction on `self` and possibly superviews up the chain.

Comment: UIImageView is contained inside a UIView and UIView is added to UIScrollView.

Comment: circleView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; and make sure there is no UIView front of image view which intercept tap events

Comment: All the circleViews are added to the UIView called TaskView. One TaskView can have many circle views. Still not calling the tapped method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this property `userInteractionEnabled` of your UIImageView at YES. Replace your code like this :

```
-(void) registerGestureRecognizer:(UIImageView *) circleView
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self; 
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    circleView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [circleView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"tapped!");
}
```

Comment: No setter method 'setIsUserInteractionEnabled:' for assignment to property

Comment: Thanks! Just made that change but still no success.

Comment: Have you add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in your .h ? it's work for me perfectly

Comment: add the property `myScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;" for you scroll view too and your view before your image view

Comment: The UIScrollView is already user interaction enabled from the interface builder. The TaskView is also user interaction enabled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38500/discussion-between-jordan-montel-and-john-doe)

Comment: I updated the code a little more maybe I am doing something wrong!

Comment: I think here is what is going on. The TaskView is full screen view and then I add UIImageView to it. So every event happens on the TaskView and then get absorbed. Although I though it should also call UIImageView recognizers but never did